# Grouping based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling to make record set as per my need.

Row where TRXCODE is 8202 contains 10% TRAMT of any other row of the record set.

So I want to a group TRXCODE 8202 row and that particular row which 10% value is in  row 8202.

Below my image will explain you better.

[image]

CREATE TABLE #TempRecords
     ( CODE VARCHAR(20),
       TRDATE DATETIME,
       TRBATCH INT,
       TRREF VARCHAR(20),
       TRXCODE INT,
       TRAMT decimal(8,2)
     );

```
GO
INSERT INTO #TempRecords
 VALUES ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 1753, 31.20),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8202, 3.12),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8104, 589.68),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, -31.20),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, -589.68),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, -3.12),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, 554.60),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, 32.18),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, 3.22),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-09-25', 8737, '0000060259', 1701, 1104.00)
```

Comment: tag your sql engine please

Answer (score 0):

use `cross join` and `dense_rank` get group id

```
with CTE as (
    select * from #TempRecords
    where trxcode = 8202
)
select T2.*,dense_rank () over (order by T1.TRAMT) GroupId 
from cte T1,(
    select * from #TempRecords
    where trxcode <> 8202   
) T2
where ROUND(T1.TRAMT/T2.TRAMT,1) = 0.1
union all
select *,dense_rank () over (order by TRAMT) GroupId from CTE
```

**Result:**

```
CODE                 TRTYPE               TRDATE                  TRBATCH     TRREF                TRXCODE     TRAMT                                   GroupId
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           1753        32.18                                   2
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8104        -31.20                                  1
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8202        -3.12                                   1
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8202        3.22                                    2
```

---

[Online Demo Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ef34b427ffe611e4fd08400adad1be92)

---

> One more thing please, row 2 and 3 should also appear in 2 separate groups , So total as per above image should 4 groups.

```
with CTE as (
    select * from #TempRecords
    where trxcode = 8202
)
, CTE2 as (
    select * from #TempRecords
    where trxcode <> 8202   
)
, CTE3 as (
    select T2.*,dense_rank () over (order by T1.TRAMT) GroupId 
    from cte T1,CTE2 T2
    where ROUND(T1.TRAMT/T2.TRAMT,1) = 0.1
)
,CTE4 as (
    select *,dense_rank () over (order by TRAMT) GroupId from CTE
)
select * from CTE3
union all
select * from CTE4
union all
select *,dense_rank () over (order by TRAMT) + (select max(GroupId) from CTE4)  GroupId  
from CTE2 where TRAMT not in (select TRAMT from CTE3)
```

**Result:**

```
CODE                 TRTYPE               TRDATE                  TRBATCH     TRREF                TRXCODE     TRAMT                                   GroupId
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------- --------------------
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8104        -31.20                                  1
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           1753        32.18                                   2
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8202        -3.12                                   1
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8202        3.22                                    2
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           1753        -589.68                                 3
ABMSC31              F                    2003-01-30 00:00:00.000 7024        0000056246           8104        554.60                                  4
```

[DEMO LINK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c13581e1dae72fe4926ac6b65b6cac8)

Comment: Thank you IT WeiHan that exactly what I was looking for, Cheers

Comment: If answer is helpful, you can mark it as answer.  thanks : )

Comment: Hi IT WeiHan, One more thing please, row 2 and 3 should also appear in 2 separate groups , So total as per above image  should 4 groups. Thanks

Comment: You are champ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi IT WeiHan, we are very close I just updated new record set and image. And as per image row no 3, 8 are marking with wrong Group id. As per image every color represent a valid group. Could you please help to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach assuming you have static data (and Oracle DB) is to use the static data as an input table and join against a multiplier table to expand the rows. I think this achieves the stated goal but it may not scale to large data sets for which you need to take a batch approach. Still, you can probably use this suggestion as a starter for building a two-pass solution where you first load the raw data into #TempRecords and then insert records using a SELECT with a multiplier.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE #TempRecords (
    CODE, TRTYPE, TRDATE, TRBATCH, TRREF, TXCODE, TRAMT
)
SELECT data.CODE, data.TRTYPE, data.TRTYPE, data.TRDATE, data.TRBATCH
    , data.TRREF, data.TRXCODE, round(m.mult * data.TRAMT, 2)
FROM (
  SELECT 'ABMSC31' CODE, 'F' TRTYPE, '2003-01-30' TRDATE, 7024 TRBATCH
    , '0000056246' TRREF, 7024 TRXCODE, 32.18 TRAMT
  FROM dual
) data
JOIN (
    SELECT 1.0 mult
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 0.1 mult
    FROM dual
) m
    ON 1=1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Saarp - Thanks for help - Cheers